# Differential of Exponential Map

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Let $(M, \langle-,-\rangle)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $p \in M$ and $v \in T_p M$. Let $\exp$ be the exponential map. How to prove $\langle (d \exp_p)_v (v), (d\exp_p)_v (v)\rangle = \langle v, v\rangle $? This is an important step in the proof of Gauss lemma and all the differential geometry books seem to think this is trivial, but I don't really see how to prove this.

Comment: Hint: Start by writing down the definition of $Exp_p$. From this, work out its derivative in radial directions. Then you will see that the claim is indeed trivial.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint! Here is what I have come up with: Consider the curve $[0, 1] \to T_p M$ given by $c(t) := v t$, then $v \in T_v(T_pM)$ is equal to $\frac{dc}{dt}$ at $t = 1$, and $Exp_p \circ c(t)$ is the geodesic curve $\gamma(t, p, v)$, so $(d~Exp_p)_v v = \frac{d Exp_p \circ c}{d t}$ has norm equal to the velocity of the geodesic, which doesn't change so is still $|v|$. - There probably should be easier ways to get this, but I am a bit struggling with the identification of $T_v(T_pM)$ to $T_pM$ at this point and sort of need to go all the way back to definition.

Comment: Yes, this is the standard argument.

Comment: Thanks for your help!